# Is there a unique identifier for Cross References in Word?

Tags: vba, ms-word

I have a macro that fetches all the hyperlinks and cross references from the document. I add each one to a listbox that is shown to the user.

When there are multiple cross references with the same text, how can I distinguish them?

For the hyperlinks, I can use `hyperlink.Name`, which will return a unique name.

What can I use to identify a cross reference? Is there a field that I can use, like `Name` for hyperlink?

I use the below code to find the cross references:

```
For Each objFld In ActiveDocument.Fields
    If objFld.Type = wdFieldRef Then
       ' add objFld
    ..
```

**EDIT :**
I am using `objFld.result.Start` to get the position of the cross reference, but it goes for a toss when the user updates any preceding cross reference.

**EDIT2 :**
I came across [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/24963386/) on SO, and it prompted me to add the below to my code:

```
objFld.ShowCodes = True
objFld.Select
Selection.Collapse wdCollapseStart
Selection.MoveStartUntil "_"
Selection.MoveEndUntil " "
refName = Selection.Text
objFld.ShowCodes = False
```

So now I am able to read the field which has `REF _Ref528247211 \h` and get `_Ref528247211` into `refName`.

However if there are multiple cross references or hyperlinks to the same target, I am not able to distinguish them.

How can I accomplish this?

**EDIT2 :**

I have a custom form where I list the hyperlinks and cross references. The user should be able to double click each item and update if needed. For this I need to distinguish each occurrence of hyperlink/cross reference

Below image shows my listbox populated from Section 1.11 referenced multiple times in page 39. The hyperlink names are all same

[image]

Comment: The location in the document or the order in which they appear would be the only thing, really. Since we have no idea about the document it's not possible to offer anything more concrete. If the document is constantly being edited so that you can't use any kind of location information then you may need to bookmark the cross-references...

Comment: Ah. Depending on how a cross-reference has been created, the bookmark name it references might be unique (Word-generated `_REF` followed by a long number.

Comment: @CindyMeister, I have added some details to the question. Will bookmarking help me distinguish different cross references to same target?

Comment: It may help if you can explain the purpose of the array of hyperlinks and cross references in a little more detail.   It may be that you are duplicating something that Word already does for free.  You may also be better off replacing your array with a scripting.dictionary of scripting.dictionaries.  The key in the first dictionary would be the name of the source of the references linked to a second sub dictionary, the second sub dictionary would use the names of the the bookmarks you create for each of your cross references (e.g Ref_XZY_bm1, REF_XZY_bm2) linked to the bookmark.

Comment: @Freeflow I have added some more details in the question

Comment: When you have an array of "Field" objects, each of those objects uniquely represents a single field in the document. It won't get any more specific than that. Is working with the objects themselves not an option?

Comment: What do you mean by 'The user should be able to double click each item and update if needed'.   You can update all fields in a document by doing Select all CTRL+A)  followed by F9.

Comment: @Freeflow when the user double clicks on an item in the listbox, the focus should go to that particular occurrence of the cross reference in the document.

Comment: Thanks for updating your question.  Unfortunately I'm still not clear on what you are actually trying to achieve.  Your list box is showing that all the cross references to Section 1.11 are the same, which is what you would expect.  The cross reference field is saying 'show text from this location in the document' and the '_Ref336427990' defines the location from where the text is being obtained.  What is it you want to see in place of the 'Ref....'

Comment: @Freeflow If there is a cross reference, I want to navigate to that particular instance; not 'Section 1.11'. I was able to do something using `objFld.result.Start`, but that fails if there was some update in the document.

Comment: I understand that but its not clear why you need to go to the cross reference.  What is it that your users have to check?

Comment: If you bookmark the cross-reference field objects then yes, you should be able to distinguish each of them. And it won't matter whether the user edits anything.

Answer (score 0):

Thanks a lot Cindy.

Based on your comment about converting cross references to bookmarks, I updated my code as below:

```
sText = hl.Name + "_" + CStr(hl.range.Start)
ActiveDocument.Bookmarks.Add Name:=sText, range:=hl.range
lstCrossRef.List(lstCrossRef.ListCount - 1, 5) = sText
```

On selecting the item from the list, I use the below code to select the cross reference in the document.

```
bmName = lstCrossRef.List(lstCrossRef.ListIndex, 5)
ActiveDocument.Bookmarks(bmName).range.Select
```